# Run Lasso regression by groups and combine results

Tags: r, dplyr, panel-data, glmnet

I would like to apply the lasso regression from glmnet on a panel dataset for each two groping variables and then combine all the coefficient results together in one dataframe where each lasso regression is identified by its two grouping variables.
Here is the code that I would like to run by group:

```
library(glmnet)
library(tidyverse)
#using Lasso variable selection 

# Store Independent variables into a Matrix

X <- as.matrix(iris[,c(2:3)])


# Store dependent variable into a vector (in this case Sepal.Length)
y <- iris$Sepal.Length 

# Choose Constrained Coefficients. In this case positive between 0 and Inf
lb <- rep(0,length(colnames( X )))
ub <- rep(Inf,length(colnames( X )))


cv_las1 <- cv.glmnet(x = X,y = y,  
          lower.limits = lb,
          upper.limits = ub)

lambda <- cv_las1$lambda.min 

# Run glmnet (with min Lambda)
las1 <- glmnet(x = X,y = y,  
       lower.limits = lb,
       upper.limits = ub,
       lambda = lambda) 

# See coefs
c.fit1 <- coef(las1) %>% as.matrix() %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()
```

Now I would like to run the above code by c(Petal.Width, Species) and have all the lasso regression results in one panel dataframe where each regression is identified by its two grouping variables.

Usually, I use dplyr group by but I'm not sure how to apply this to something like glmnet package where the inputs need to be specified. In my actual dataset I have more than millions of combinations of the two grouping values so I'm looking for something scalable and function-based.

The following code works but now my problem is to apply this efficiently to  a large dataset:

```
lass <- function(z) {
  data <- z

  X <- as.matrix(data[,c(2:3)])
  
  
  # Store dependent variable into a vector (in this case Sepal.Length)
  y <- data$Sepal.Length 
  
  # Choose Constrained Coefficients. In this case positive between 0 and Inf
  lb <- rep(0,length(colnames( X )))
  ub <- rep(Inf,length(colnames( X )))
  
  
  cv_las1 <- cv.glmnet(x = X,y = y,  
                       lower.limits = lb,
                       upper.limits = ub)
  
  lambda <- cv_las1$lambda.min 
  
  # Run glmnet (with min Lambda)
  las1 <- glmnet(x = X,y = y,  
                 lower.limits = lb,
                 upper.limits = ub,
                 lambda = lambda) 
  
  # See coefs
  c.fit1 <- coef(las1) %>% as.matrix() %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()
  return(c.fit1)
}


result = iris %>% 
  group_by(Species,Petal.Width) %>%
  do(rbind(lass(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works but now my problem is to apply this efficiently to  a large dataset:

```
lass <- function(z) {
  data <- z

  X <- as.matrix(data[,c(2:3)])
  
  
  # Store dependent variable into a vector (in this case Sepal.Length)
  y <- data$Sepal.Length 
  
  # Choose Constrained Coefficients. In this case positive between 0 and Inf
  lb <- rep(0,length(colnames( X )))
  ub <- rep(Inf,length(colnames( X )))
  
  
  cv_las1 <- cv.glmnet(x = X,y = y,  
                       lower.limits = lb,
                       upper.limits = ub)
  
  lambda <- cv_las1$lambda.min 
  
  # Run glmnet (with min Lambda)
  las1 <- glmnet(x = X,y = y,  
                 lower.limits = lb,
                 upper.limits = ub,
                 lambda = lambda) 
  
  # See coefs
  c.fit1 <- coef(las1) %>% as.matrix() %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()
  return(c.fit1)
}


result = iris %>% 
  group_by(Species,Petal.Width) %>%
  do(rbind(lass(.)))
```